# Browserify multiple transforms error

Tags: javascript, node.js, browserify, grunt-browserify, envify

Trying to run multiple transforms with browserify.

I have the following files in a directory

- dev.json
- stage.json
- prod.json
- index.js

The json files are environment specific config files.

index.js :

`var mode = process.env.APP_ENV;
 module.exports = require('./' + mode + '.json');`

I am using the envify transform to pick between dev/prod/stage and configurify to evaluate dynamic expressions.

If I just run the envify it works fine but when I use envify followed by configurify, I get an error saying "./undefined.json" not found.

[image]

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: At some point the `mode` variable is not being set, or you are trying to access it out with its scope.

Comment: @DanielWaghorn my understanding is that the transforms happen in order so mode should be equal to "dev" as per the first command. Correct me if my understanding is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Took some to understand how browserify transforms work using streams. Apparently the configuriy transform was not using the stream and instead reading the file form disk. Opened an  [issue](https://github.com/fgnass/configurify/issues/2).